# Yii2 - JSONP response returns nothing (blank) and does not work, but JSON does

Tags: php, json, yii, jsonp, yii2

I am using Yii2, and for what it's worth, I know the basics, and have been programming for a while. This is probably from a lack of documentation in this area (Yii2 JSONP and Responses). All I find is examples of returning a JSON response, none showing a JSONP response.

I started here, the Yii Cookbook: 
https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/response-formats.md

It only shows examples of JSON and XML, but not JSONP. It states to use `FORMAT_JSONP`. So I swapped the JSON example with JSONP. Go to the URL, nothing, just a blank white page. So I var_dump() the data, and yes the data is there!

So after searching Google for "yii2 jsonp", "yii2 jsonp error", "yii2 jsonp doesn't work", along with a few other variations, I found nothing.. I searched here on SO, and only 2 questions show up for "yii2 jsonp", neither were of any help.

I proceeded to the Yii2 docs.
Here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-responses.html
Again, no JSONP example and not much talk about it other than `FORMAT_JSONP` is a valid format type...

I can use JSON just fine, however I am trying to populate a Google Map with data from a JSONP response, hence why I need JSONP.

Here is my Controller:

```
public function actionMapapi()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSONP;
    $data = User::find()->all();

    return $data;
}
```

When I go to the URL, it's just white. I can place a die('here') before declaring the response->format, and it prints "here" on the page. So the controller is being accessed just fine. If I swap `FORMAT_JSONP` with `FORMAT_JSON` it works perfect, it's just not JSONP.

It seems there is a gap on how to exactly handle JSONP in the Yii2 docs, and not much talking about it online (that I could possibly find).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to return an array that defines your `callback` and `data`. This is fairly hidden, and mentioned here: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-jsonresponseformatter.html

It states:

> **$useJsonp** Whether to use JSONP response format. When this is true, the response data must be an array consisting of data and callback members. The latter should be a JavaScript function name while the former will be passed to this function as a parameter.

With virtually no examples that I could find, I just tried the obvious:

```
return ['data' => $arrayData, 'callback' => 'myCallback'];
```

**It Worked!**

Full source of my Controller:

```
public function actionMapapi()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSONP;
    $callback = 'mapApiCallback';
    $data = User::find()->all();

    return ['callback' => $callback, 'data' => $data];
}
```

**NOTE:** No, I am not populating my map with the users. It's just an example, and the data prints on the screen just fine. I still have to code it to pull my map data to pass to my Google map.

If anyone is interested, I am using: [2Amigos: Yii2 Google Maps Library](https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-google-maps-library)

I don't know if it currently supports populating a map with JSONP data, but I will probably extend it if I have to.